# Error When Running my Discord Bot on Python Anywhere

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py, pythonanywhere

I made a Discord Bot using Python 3.6. It runs and behaves perfectly when run on my computer, yet when I run it on PythonAnywhere, I get this message. I installed Discord.py and all necessary modules. Please help. I am not that very good with complex programming talk, and not at all good with web talk, so please answer as simply as you can. Does this issue only happen with PythonAnywhere or all remote hosting sites?

```
01:42 ~ $ python3.6 MyCoolBot.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/CompuGenius/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 601, in _create_direc
t_connection
    local_addr=self._local_addr)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 778, in create_connection
    raise exceptions[0]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 765, in create_connection
    yield from self.sock_connect(sock, address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 450, in sock_connect
    return (yield from fut)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 480, in _sock_connect_cb
    raise OSError(err, 'Connect call failed %s' % (address,))
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connect call failed ('104.16.58.5', 443)
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/CompuGenius/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 304, in connect
    yield from self._create_connection(req)
  File "/home/CompuGenius/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 578, in _create_conne
ction
    transport, proto = yield from self._create_direct_connection(req)
  File "/home/CompuGenius/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 624, in _create_direc
t_connection
    (req.host, req.port, exc.strerror)) from exc
aiohttp.errors.ClientOSError: [Errno 111] Can not connect to discordapp.com:443 [Connect call failed ('104.16.
58.5', 443)]
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MyCoolBot.py", line 39, in <module>
    client.run('MY_BOT_TOKEN')
  File "/home/CompuGenius/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 519, in run
    self.loop.run_until_complete(self.start(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 468, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/home/CompuGenius/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 490, in start
    yield from self.login(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/CompuGenius/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 416, in login
    yield from getattr(self, '_login_' + str(n))(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/CompuGenius/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 346, in _login_1
    data = yield from self.http.static_login(token, bot=is_bot)
  File "/home/CompuGenius/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 258, in static_login
    data = yield from self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "/home/CompuGenius/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 137, in request
    r = yield from self.session.request(method, url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/CompuGenius/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 555, in __iter__
    resp = yield from self._coro
  File "/home/CompuGenius/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 198, in _request
    conn = yield from self._connector.connect(req)
  File "/home/CompuGenius/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 314, in connect
    .format(key, exc.strerror)) from exc
aiohttp.errors.ClientOSError: [Errno 111] Cannot connect to host discordapp.com:443 ssl:True [Can not connect to discordapp.com:443 [Connect call failed ('104.16.58.5', 443)]]
Unclosed client session
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x7f4b25d81be0>
```

Comment: This is because PythonAnywhere requires a proxy in such a way that the aiohttp websockets don't support.  There's a thread on their forums about it here: https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/7384/

Comment: You just leaked your bot token. I'm going to edit your question to not have it anymore, but you should **regenerate your token immediately.** Go to your bot's page at https://discordapp.com/developers/applications/, find where you pulled the token from to begin with, and click "Regenerate."

Comment: @c.berger why is that such a problem? Does it give others access? Because my bot WAS changed!

Comment: @CompuGenius an unscrupulous user *could* have used it to run thier own application as your bot, yes.

Comment: Thanks, I deleted every instance, so they're won't be any more problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because PythonAnywhere requires a proxy in such a way that the aiohttp websockets don't support.  There's a thread on their forums about it here: https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/7384/ (See @Patrick Haugh's comment above)